# I can't see through the reference image in wireframe

Tags: wireframe

[image]

I can't see through the reference image in wireframe
that view is truly wireframe
Is there anyone who knows what happened?

Answer (score 1):

You mean see the reference image through the objects in your scene? If that is the case one option would be to press "Shift-Z" in order to see the scene transparent. There is of course a button as well for it next to the wireframe button. in the picture below I have both wireframe mode and show x ray selected  [image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness